Bind ParamSec to a method but with a function inside of an object attributes
I would like to bind the arguments hints of a function to a method, but the function is a constructor of a BaseModel subclass that is inside of my class attributes.
This is my code:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic

ModelT = TypeVar("ModelT", bound=BaseModel)


class ModelMaker(Generic[ModelT]):

    def __init__(self, model: Type[ModelT]) -> None:
        self.model: Type[ModelT] = model

    def create(self, *args, **kwargs) -> ModelT:
        return self.model(*args, **kwargs)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


maker = ModelMaker(MyModel)

instance = maker.create() # i would like to get on vscode:
# (method) def create(*, name: str, age: int) -> MyModel
# and not:
# (method) def create(...) -> MyModel

I tried using ParamSpec but there is no way to bind the ParamSpec as .model.__init__.

Not terribly well tested (in my test, pyright complains that it can't resolve pydantic), but it appears you can replace Type[MyModel] with Callable[P, MyModel] (and make MyModel generic in P) to transfer the signature of MyModel.__init__ to create.
With
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic, ParamSpec, Callable

P = ParamSpec('P')

ModelT = TypeVar("ModelT", bound=BaseModel)


class ModelMaker(Generic[ModelT, P]):

    def __init__(self, model: Callable[P, ModelT]) -> None:
        self.model: Callable[P, ModelT] = model

    def create(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> ModelT:
        return self.model(*args, **kwargs)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

    def __init__(self, n: str, a: int):
        self.n = n
        self.a = a


maker = ModelMaker(MyModel)
reveal_type(maker.create)

I get
% py312/bin/pyright tmp.py
/Users/chepner/tmp.py
  /Users/chepner/tmp.py:1:6 - error: Import "pydantic" could not be resolved (reportMissingImports)
  /Users/chepner/tmp.py:28:13 - information: Type of "maker.create" is "(n: str, a: int) -> MyModel"
1 error, 0 warnings, 1 information

This is, of course, more general than your original code, as model can be any callable that returns a BaseModel, not just an instance of BaseModel itself.
